# Determine if $B:=\{(r\cosθ,r\sinθ)∈\mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0<r<1,0<θ<3π\}$ is open or closed or not open and not closed

Tags: calculus

> Determine if $B:=\{(r\cosθ,r\sinθ)∈\mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0<r<1,0<θ<3π\}$ is open or closed or not open and not closed

I'm not even sure what this area looks like  (I'm guessing a parabola) but I know I have to show that  it is possible to construct a ball or circle area with any origin in the parameter and have it be small enough to be a subset of $B$ and not violate the restriction.

Comment: It's the interior of a circle, center and a radius excluded, and it's pretty open (I think $2\pi$ does make more sense)

Comment: Which radius is excluded?

Comment: So just the area of a circle. How do you get the origin and radius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f: (x,y) \mapsto x^{2} + y^{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then $f$ is continuous and $B = f^{(-1)}(]0,1[)$, the preimage of $]0,1[$ under $f$. Since $]0,1[$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.